# Wondering why I keep receiving errors

Tags: python

I'm getting confused with functions as i have just tried to employ the if and else 
functions and i can't get them working...

```
def instructions():
   print ("Hello, and welcome to the programme")

def getInput(b):
        b=int(input("Enter how many bags of Java coffe you have purchased:  "))

if  b <= 25:
    bonus = b + 0:

if  b >= 25:
     else:
         b <= 49:
        bonus = b * 0.05:

if  b <= 50:
else:
    b >= 99:
        bonus = b * 0.1:


if  b >= 100:
    bonus = b * 0.2:








...
instructions()
...
print("")
...
getInput()
```

the else on the second line is coming up as an error and so to id the b near the top.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: check your indentation and `if else` clause.

Comment: That's not going to run. The indentation is incoherent.

Comment: You have 2 empty `if` blocks

Comment: Wherever you have `if` you need some indented code after it. Wherever you have `else` it needs to come _after_ an indented `if` block (not inside it).

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you out a bit

```
if  b <= 25:
    bonus = b + 0:

elif  b >= 25 and b <= 49:
    bonus = b * 0.05:

elif  b >= 50 and b <= 99:
    bonus = b * 0.1:
else:
    bonus = b * 0.2:
```

Should give you more of what you expect.
Also you will have issues with your get input it is expecting an argument when it should be returning one it should look more like this:

```
def getInput():
    return int(input("Enter how many bags of Java coffe you have purchased:  "))
```

You'll probably want to indent all of the bonus code into a function of its own and pass the return from getInput into it

Answer (score 0):

Your code indentation is incorrect - this is important in python; it is part of the syntax.

The logic could do with a bit of cleaning up too;

```
def instructions():
  print ("Hello, and welcome to the programme")


def getInput(b):
  b=int(input("Enter how many bags of Java coffe you have purchased:  "))

  bonus = 0:

  if 25 < b <= 50:
    bonus = b * 0.05

  elif b <= 99:
    bonus = b * 0.1

  elif b >= 100:
    bonus = b * 0.2:

  return b, bonus

...
instructions()
...
bagsBought, bonus = getInput()
print "You bought %i, and got %i bonus bags!" % (bagsBounght, bonus)
```